# How to sort a nested array by element count in Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, sorting

I have the following array and I would like to sort it in descending order based on the count of the number of elements in the nested array.

```
array = [[2], [0,3], [0,1], [1,2,4,5], [1,6,10], [], [7,8], [], [], [8], [9]]
```

After sorting, it should look like this

```
array = [[1,2,4,5], [1,6,10], [0,3], [0,1], [7,8], [8], [9], [2], [], [], []]
```

I thought of counting the elements and saving it within the nested array, but I have no idea how to sort it after. Eventually, I hope to be able to use the msort function in Ruby.

Comment: `array.sort_by(&:count).reverse`, this has probably been ask before ...

Answer (score 6):

That's just

```
array.sort_by(&:size).reverse
  #=> [[1, 2, 4, 5], [1, 6, 10], [0, 3], [0, 1], [7, 8], [2], [8], [9], [], [], []]
```

Another way:

```
array.sort_by { |a| -a.size }
```

And one more:

```
array.sort { |a,b| b.size <=> a.size }
```

Oh, yes, with Ruby v2.2+:

```
array.max_by(array.size, &:size)
```

Comment: Or even `array.min_by(array.size) { |a| -a.size }` ;-)

Comment: @Stefan, I actually considered that (momentarily). :-) Strangely, the answers to the question for which this question is a dup do not include my #4.